# Fortran's SIGN function in Julia

Tags: julia

Exists there a function in Julia that is equivalent to the `SIGN(A,B)` function in Fortran?

`SIGN(A,B)` in Fortran returns the value of `A` with the sign of `B`.  If `B > 0` then the result is `ABS(A)`, else it is `-ABS(A)`. For instance, `SIGN(10,-1)` would give you `-10`.

Comment: In Fortran there are four distinct cases for the arguments of `sign` to consider, not just the two mentioned.  I will expand if you feel that necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `copysign` function that does what you want.

The only distinction from what you have specified is that `copysign(1.0, 0.0)` return `1.0` and you specified it to be `-1.0` (by saying `B>0`), but I guess you want this to evaluate to `1.0` like `copysign` behaves. Right?. Note that `copysign(1.0, -0.0)` is `-1.0`.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Check Bogumil's answer. Turns out there is a function in `Base` that does this.

I don't think there is a function in `Base` that does this. However, adding a new method to `sign` is an easy solution:

```
Base.sign(a, b) = abs(a)*sign(b)
```

You can use `methods(sign)` to check that your new method won't clash with any existing methods. In this case, it definitely won't since all existing methods only have a single input.

The behaviour of the new method will also be consistent with all existing input types, eg `sign(missing, -1)` will return `missing`, and `sign(true, false)` will return `false`.

Alternatively, you could come up with your own new function name.

Comment: Maybe `ofsign(b, a)` would be more clear, and moreover consistent with `oftype(b, a)`.